# jQuery function that run some codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I have 10 checkbox in my page and I want some code run after any checkbox checked.
look at my code please:

```
var width = 0;

    $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
       if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       width+=5;
       }
       else{
       width-=5;
       }
   //this is the code that i want it run after any of checkboxes clicked
   if (width <= 25){do something}
   if ( width > 25 && width <= 50){do something}
   if ( width > 50 &&  width <= 75){do something}
   if ( width > 75 && width <= 100){do something}
   });
```

Is there any way to create a function or something else to run these codes inside every checkboxes and prevent from repeating these codes?

### **Thanks for answers. but i want to repeat just four "if" at the bottom of the page and "width+=5" or "width-=5" is not repetitive.**

Comment: `'#checkbox1'` is targeting only one of them. can you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind two event listeners *change* for the specific checkbox, and *click*, for all the checboxes

so your non-repetitive code on the selected checbox only

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        width += 5;
    }
    else {
        width -= 5;
    }
}
```

the repetitive code applied on all the checkboxes

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
           //this is the code that i want it run after any of checkboxes clicked
          if (width <= 25){do something}
          if ( width > 25 && width <= 50){do something}
          if ( width > 50 &&  width <= 75){do something}
          if ( width > 75 && width <= 100){do something}

    });
```

or use what A.B suggested `$('input:checkbox')`

Comment: Thanks for answer. but i want to repeat just four "if" at the bottom of the page and "width+=5" or "width-=5" is not repetitive.

Comment: you can register both events, one to a particular checkbox, and one applied to any checkbox. I've edited an answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use general selector for checkbox `:checkbox` [refrence](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
       if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       width+=5;
       }
       else{
       width-=5;
       }
   //this is the code that i want it run after any of checkboxes clicked
   if (width <= 25){do something}
   if ( width > 25 && width <= 50){do something}
   if ( width > 50 &&  width <= 75){do something}
   if ( width > 75 && width <= 100){do something}
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but i want to repeat just four "if" at the bottom of the page and "width+=5" or "width-=5" is not repetitive.

Comment: @user2781069 this needs to be there for every checkbox. this isnt repetition i guess